# Solow residual with cost minimization, calculus (Roeger, 1995)

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, mathematical-economics, economic-growth

I am trying to get a good understanding of the steps involved in solving the dual of a maximization problem, namely cost minimization. At some point (last two steps), the author ends up with the following function for marginal cost growth:
$$\Delta mc=\left [\frac{WN}{C(\cdot )}  \right ]\Delta w+\left [1-\frac{WN}{C(\cdot )}  \right ]\Delta r -\Delta e$$
Where the relation between price and marginal cost is given by:
$$(1-B)P=MC=\frac{G(W,R)}{E}$$
From this latter equation, the difference between the change in price and a weighted average of changes in factor prices, the dual or price-based Solow residual is defined as:
$$\alpha \Delta w +(1-\alpha)\Delta r-\Delta p=-B(\Delta p-\Delta r)+(1-B)\Delta e$$
Where the weights for the factor prices are the wage share in output for wages and its complement for capital costs ($\alpha$) and ($1-\alpha$).

I can't figure out how you get to this last step. I tried differentiating the marginal cost equation and substituting in the second one, but I'm missing some terms. The problem comes from the following paper: "Can Imperfect Competition Explain the Difference between Primal and Dual Productivity Measures? Estimates for U.S. Manufacturing" (1995).

*$\Delta x$ is the log difference of the variable X.

Answer (score 2):

Equation (4b) in the paper gives:
$$
\Delta mc_t = \frac{E_t N_t W_t}{Y_t G(.)}\Delta w_t + \frac{E_t K_t R_t}{Y_t G(.)} \Delta r_t - \Delta e_t. \tag{I}
$$
Next we also have equation (5) in the paper:
$$
(1-B)P_t = MC_T = \frac{G(.)}{E_t}. \tag{II}
$$
Now substitute $(II)$ into $(I)$ to get:
$$
\Delta mc_t = \frac{N_t W_t}{P_t Y_t (1-B)}\Delta w_t + \frac{K_t R_t}{P_t Y_t (1-B)} \Delta r_t - \Delta e_t. \tag{III}
$$
Now, we define the wage cost over the total revenue to be $\alpha_t$.
$$
\alpha_t = \frac{N_t W_t}{P_t Y_t}. \tag{IV}
$$
Also, by the CRS assumption, we have that $\frac{N_t W_t}{C(.)} + \frac{R_t K_t}{C(.)} = 1$. Dividing this by $P_t Y_t/C(.)$ and using $C(.) = G(.)Y_t/E_t$ as equation (2) in the paper, we get:
$$
\frac{N_t W_t}{P_t Y_t} + \frac{R_t K_t}{P_t Y_t} = \frac{C(.)}{P_t Y_t} = \frac{G(.)Y_t}{E_t P_t Y_t} = \frac{G(.)}{E_t P_t} = (1-B) \tag{V}
$$
The last equality comes from comes from $(II)$
Using $(IV)$ in $(V)$ gives:
$$
\frac{R_t K_t}{P_t Y_t} = (1-B) - \alpha_t. \tag{VI}
$$
Now substitute $(IV)$ and $(VI)$ into $(III)$ to get:
$$
\Delta mc_t = \frac{\alpha_t}{(1-B)} \Delta w_t + \frac{1 - \alpha_t - B}{(1-B)}\Delta r_t - \Delta e_t. \tag{VII}
$$
Also log differentiating the first part of $(II)$ gives $\Delta p_t = \Delta mc_t$ so substituting this in $(VII)$  (and multiplying both sides by $(1-B)$ finally produces:
$$
\Delta p_t (1-B) = \alpha_t \Delta w_t + (1 - \alpha_t - B) \Delta r_t - \Delta e_t. \tag{VIII}
$$
The expression that you are looking for is a simple rearrangement of $(VIII)$.